# Windows 10 UAP: Share data on Facebook

Tags: facebook, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Is it possible to correctly share data on Facebook post using `DataRequest` and `DataTransferManager` classes?

I am trying to create a Facebook post using `DataTransferManager.DataRequested` and `DataTransferManager.TargetApplicationChosen` handlers.

I have Facebook web page and I am providing link to it by calling `dataRequest.Data.SetWebLink(facebookWebpageUri)` in my `DataTransferManager.TargetApplicationChosen` handlers when chosen app is "facebook".

The problem is that Facebook should scrap the webpage for the data it shows in the post as it does in my Android and iOS apps but in my Windows 10 UAP it does not do this. It only shows the title and the text set by `dataRequest.Data.SetText` if I provide it before invoking share using `DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI()`

Answer (score 0):

There are two type of app for sharing Interaction: one is source app, the other one is target app.

As a share source(UWP) app, we handle the source data, for your scenario, the facebook is the share target.

What we can do is dealing with the data you want to share, which we have done already. As the target app, facebook need to be able to resolve this source data, this work can not be done by the source app.

What you can try to do is:

- Contact with the facebook to submit a suggestion.
- Use the [web api of facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/).
- Try to find and use some third-party libraries of WinRT.